# having trouble fixing dependency cycle in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

One of my redux actions requires access to a class that manages api requests.
However in my api requests class, I wrote a method that requires importing the data store. I then began getting the following error:

> Cannot access '**WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT**' before initialization

I looked up the error and mentions It is due to a dep cycle, it seems that this pattern is causing the importing of an uninitialized data store.
summery: Since my redux slice imports the api class and the api class depends on the redux store how can i restructure my code to fix this pattern?

Comment: Without seeing any code it will be hard to say anything. Why does your method need to import the store for instance? That seems a bit weird.

Comment: We can't realistically help address any issue(s) with code we can't see. Please [edit] the post to include a relevant [mcve].

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie i cut out the fat and gave an example of what is happening structurally. I personally don't consider it "weird" for a class to have access the store. This pattern is very common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We specifically advise Redux users that [you should *never* import the store directly into other files, except the main app entry point file](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#only-one-redux-store-per-app), because of this sort of import cycle problem.

The *best* approach here would be to restructure your logic so that this class file doesn't need to use the store at all.

As a secondary fallback, [you can expose a setter from that module that saves the `store` reference, and call that setter from the entry point on startup](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-can-i-use-the-redux-store-in-non-component-files).

Comment: thank you so much. The fallback is what I needed. It makes sense how this resolves the dependency issue.